# Vue and Google Tag Manager

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-tag-manager

I added GTM script on my application(VueJs) in public/index.html:

```
<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-XXXXXX');</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
```

However I getting the error

[image]

My website doesn't use the JQuery. How I can resolve the issue?

Comment: I think you'll have to use [vue-gtm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-gtm) in order to implement google tag manager with VueJS. You can see sample implementation [here](https://bestofvue.com/repo/mib200-vue-gtm-vuejs-google-analytics).

Comment: @Salvino I tried to use `vue-gtm` however I also getting the error :(

Comment: In your snapshot we can see the `Uncaught RefernceError:` but not the entire `stacktrace`. Can you expand that and post the full stacktrace in the question so that we can help you track the dependency that's causing this issue?

Comment: @Salvino, sure I have updated my question

Comment: By any chance, did you keep the <script> tag of google tag manager in `index.html` even after implementing `vue-gtm`? After implementing `vue-gtm` make sure you don't have any explicit google tag manger scripts loader into the `DOM`.

Comment: @Salvino I am just add GTM script into `<head>` tags

Comment: Can you remove it? Do not do anything extra which is not mentioned in the `vue-gtm` implementation. I have a feeling the external script you're loading is based on `jQuery` and hence it's throwing that error. Let `vue-gtm` inject the `gtag` in the DOM on its own.

Comment: Also I removed GTM script and setup only `vue-gtm` doesn't work ;(

Answer (score 0):

The snippet itself doesn't have references to Jquery. The code it loads, however, may. To test it properly, open the network request blocking window in your dev tools, and block gtm. Reload the page, see if the error still occurs. If it doesn't, then indeed we have a jquery reference in the container somewhere.

Let's find it. You should go to the GTM container that has the same ID that you're loading, go to admin, and export the whole container in a neat json. Open the json and look for jquery. Find what uses it and rewrite the code to pure JS.

Using jquery or other third party JS libraries in tag managers is not a good practice exactly because of the cases like this one. You don't want unneeded dependencies in tag managers. While jquery may be useful (arguably) for front-end code because of how it creates a more universally cross-platform interface, tag managers should never be used for document.writes, dom mutations and even dom scraping should be seen as temporary/hacky solutions.